# Payment gateway for WordPress and Drupal

Tags: payment-processor

We have to build a payment gateway for CiviCRM in South Africa would like to know what all the modules are that are capable of taking payments?

We CiviContribute and CiviEvents makes use of payment gateways but are there any other modules we need to consider when specking this project out?

For both Drupal and WordPress please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CiviMember also intersects with the payment plugin, potentially.

But the basic functionality can be built without reference to how it's used.

You'll want to start with this:

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/payment-processors/

Comment: thank you Alan, much appreciated. Does this apply to WordPress and Drupal?

Comment: Yes, the payment plugins are CMS agnostic (assuming they are well written).